# Planet or regions offline maps between two zoom levels

Tags: tiles, rendering, generate-tiles, tile-server

I need offline maps to be included in the application I am developing. I decided to use marble https :// marble.kde.org/
to do this. Marble uses openstreetmap tileserver (among others). 
What I need is to be able to access maps offline because my application hasn't got Internet access. 
The first I did was to download tiles I wanted from marble.

The problem is that I don't want the openstreetmap map style, the only thing I need is coasts and relief, so I decided to create a tile server to supply tiles to marble. 
I did that following these tutorial
https://ramneekpaulsingh.wordpress.com/2015/01/22/testing-your-tile-server-step-1/
http://switch2osm.org/serving-tiles/manually-building-a-tile-server-14-04/

My tile server is working well because I can connect to the address http:// yourserveraddress/osm_tiles/0/0/0.png, and the gis database contains information after the osm data importation, because if I make the request 
psql -d gis -c "select name from planet_osm_point where place='city';"

I got a list of names.
The renderd daemon is working fine to, because I can render manually:
./render_list -m default -a -z 0 -Z 10

But after reading the questions here, I realised that maybe it wasn't necessary, because the only thing I need is the generated tiles.

I have two questions:

1. Despite of the fact that my tile server is working right, because I can connect to the address http:// yourserveraddress/osm_tiles/0/0/0.png, and   I don't know how to ask it for requests. I have tried to change the downloadUrl line in openstreetmap.dgml marble configuration file for openstreetmap tile server, but my tile server seems not to be aware of the fact that marble is making requests. How can I test the rendering is being performed and it is right?
2. Do I really need to create a tile server? Can I render a specific area between two zoom levels and generate the tile png images in order to copy them to the host in which my application is going to be launched and marble will be able to access them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the article [Rendering](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Rendering) in the OSM wiki, there is at least the program [Maperitive](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Maperitive) which can load raw OSM data for areas of a specific size, and the you can produce tiles by pre-defined or self-created map styles for zoom-level z... to z...

After processing you have a bunch of pre-rendered tiles for offline use in a directory structure like used in OSM.

Maybe this fits to your needs of "no-tile-server" solution.